# NSNumber!? is not convertible to NSNumber

Tags: swift2, nsnumber

I am learning swift and follow a tutorial I found on the internet, and I got an error doing one of the things that are said.

```
let major = beacons[indexPath.row].major as NSNumber
```

I got an error on that :

> 'NSNumber!? is not convertible to NSNumber'

How can I do this conversion ?

Comment: What's the tutorial?

Comment: And which Swift version are you using?

Comment: I am using Swift 2 with Xcode 7.

And the tutorial is : http://cityos.io/tutorial/1031/Swift-tutorial-with-iBeacons-Beginners-guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your tutorial instead of this code:

```
let major = beacons[indexPath.row].major as NSNumber
var majorString = major.stringValue
```

Use this code:

```
let major = self.beacons[indexPath.row].major  //Don't cast this as NSNumber
let majorString = "\(major)"                   //convert it to string this way
```

Or you can convert `major` into string this way:

```
let majorString = major!!.stringValue
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Happy to help you..:)